# Loop on multiple arrays in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have multiple arrays that I need to print on a sheet.
my idea was like:

```
tables = array("table1","table2",....)
for z= lbound(tables,1)to ubound(tableaux,1)
for j= lbound(tables(z),1)to ubound(tables(z),1)
for k= lbound(tables(z),2)to ubound(tables(z),2)

msg tables(z)(j,k)
next
next
next
```

is there a way to do that?  otherwise i will need to recopy and reuse same code for each table.

thanks in advance

Comment: What are "table1","table2"? `ListObjects` having that names? Even so, are all of them in the same sheet? Speaking for a jagged array (arrays in an array), should they be also arrays, but by mistake you place their name between double quotes? In order to be helped you should say something more about things in the code, at least...

Comment: table1 table2 are arrays that have been created before 
for ie table1 is 10 to 4 length
for ie table2 is 5 to 6 length

Comment: Then, please test the adapted code supplied in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub LoopInTablesArrays()
   Dim tables, tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject, table1, table2
   Dim z As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table23") 'use here an existing table sheet/name
   Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table26") 'set an existing table
   
   table1 = tbl1.Range.value  'place the table range in an array
   table2 = tbl2.Range.value  'place the table range in an array
   tables = Array(table1, table2) 'you may place here as many arrays as you need

   For z = LBound(tables, 1) To UBound(tables, 1)
        For j = LBound(tables(z), 1) To UBound(tables(z), 1)
            For k = LBound(tables(z), 2) To UBound(tables(z), 2)
                Debug.Print tables(z)(j, k)
            Next k
        Next j
   Next z
End Sub
```

It returns in `Immediate Window`. Sending a lot of messages may be annoying...

To see `Immediate Window`, press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE.